# After restore ubuntu image hangs on black pointer

Tags: restore

I need to install serveral pc's with XUBUNTU. 
Started with installing one and adding the applications i needed. 
I made an image with our imaging tool : ZENworks.

Then i restored the partition on another pc with the same specs and it booted with only a black pointer....

I have removed the UID's from the /etc/fstab file and changed it by the /dev/sd...
Made an image again and restored but again the black pointer.

What am I missing?

Kr,

Joeri

Answer (score 1):

ZENworks is not made for imaging of Ubuntu systems.
Novell only supports imaging of Enterprise OS's like SLES and RHEL.